# How to resize the collection view cells according to device screen size?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios10

I noticed that the cells would always follow the definition in size inspector. Even if I have already applied UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

[image]

[image]

So that's how it looks. But I want the cells to rather look like how it was on a smaller iphone screen.

[image]

Comment: are you using swift?

Comment: You have to use multiplier from superview for cell creation, than it will automatically adjust according to screen size.

Comment: Yes I'm using swift. I also noticed something, the collection view cells seems to follow the Cell Size defined in Size Inspector. Even if I programatically resize the cell using collectionViewLayout.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Implement `sizeForItemAt` method according to the view's frame size

**Swift**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let height = view.frame.size.height
    let width = view.frame.size.width
    // in case you you want the cell to be 40% of your controllers view
    return CGSize(width: width * 0.4, height: height * 0.4)
}
```

**Objective C**

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
   sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;
   CGFloat width  = self.view.frame.size.width;
   // in case you you want the cell to be 40% of your controllers view
   return CGSizeMake(width * 0.4, height * 0.4);
 }
```

Comment: So do I put this code inside func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize ......?

Comment: its a UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method . UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout inherits from UICollectionViewDelegate which means you should implement this method and change the protocol UICollectionViewDelegate to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout after adding this method, otherwise this method wont be called

Comment: I also noticed something, the collection view cells seems to follow the Cell Size defined in Size Inspector. Even if I programatically resize the cell using collectionViewLayout

Comment: did you change the delegate you conform to? and checked that

Comment: - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
   sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Great! I missed that part. So I looked into the definition of protocols and applied the right delegate. It's working now.

Comment: Don't forget to about UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout :)

Comment: We also need to set `Estimate Size` to `None` in Size Inspector from xib/storyboard.

Comment: implements UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method before calling sizeForItemAt. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Adding this code caused problem in cellForItemAt with this error "Value of type '(UICollectionView, UICollectionViewLayout, IndexPath) -> CGSize' has no member 'dequeueReusableCell' "  The solution to this, is to place the SizeForItemAt function on top of the CellForItemAt as apparently the latter calls the former-- so order matters.

Answer (score 17):

Swift 4

Multiply the collectionView's frame width/height in an implementation of the `sizeForItemAt` method.

```
class yourClassName: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: self.myCollectionView.frame.height / 6 * 5, height: self.myCollectionView.frame.height / 6 * 5)

        }


}
```

`self.myCollectionView` is the reference from you collection view Item 
it's important to implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

And because it will not fit another cell you will have only one row.

Comment: Thanks... and thanks to @MiratIgrabrimov's comment on another answer, eventually realised I was missing conformance to the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol, so it wasn't being called.

Answer (score 6):

You should try using a simple equation when setting your cell size instead of number like so:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 2, height: 350)
    }
```

dividing it by 2 will mean that the cell always be half of the screens size, taking away and kind of minimumLineSpacing functions and/or and UIEdgeInset methods you have called. Hope this helps.

Comment: I also noticed something, the collection view cells seems to follow the Cell Size defined in Size Inspector. Even if I programatically resize the cell using collectionViewLayout

Answer (score 6):

Some of you might need to do this too: In the Storyboard, go to the collectionviewFlowLayout (yellow cube) inside the Collection View, then go to the Size Inspector, make sure the "Estimated Size" is set to "None".

Answer (score 5):

In swift 3, You can resize collection view cell as per the screen using `collectionViewLayout` property.

I.e.

```
   let numberOfCell = 3
   let cellSpecing = 10
   if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (screenSize.width - (cellSpecing * (numberOfCell + 1))) / numberOfCell, height: cellHeight)
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**in Swift 5** 
You can just extend your view controller from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implement this method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let height = collectionView.frame.height
        let width  = collectionView.frame.width
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

in this example I make the width of cells equal to the width of the `CollectionView` you can adapt it depends on your need.

Answer (score 2):

As per my experience, you have to use `UICollectionView` methods to get device-specific collection view cell size as per the below methods you can get dynamic width & height of collection view cell.

```
// Dynamic width & height
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    float cellSize = collectionView.frame.size.width/values.count;
    return CGSizeMake(cellSize - 10, collectionView.frame.size.height);
}

//For top/bottom/left/right padding method
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 1);
}



- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    float width = collectionView.frame.size.width;
    float spacing = [self collectionView:collectionView layout:collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:section];
    int numberOfCells = (width + spacing) / (cellSize + spacing);
    int inset = (width + spacing - numberOfCells * (cellSize + spacing) ) / 2;
    
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, inset, 0, inset);
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *) collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger) section
{
    return 1.0;
}
```

Hope this will help you to design your cell-based on device size.

Answer (score -1):

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let theWidth = (_screenSize.width - (15*3))/2    // it will generate 2 column 
    let theHeight = (_screenSize.height - (10*2))/3   // it will generate 3 Row 
    return CGSize(width: theWidth ,height: theHeight)
}
```

Comment: I also noticed something, the collection view cells seems to follow the Cell Size defined in Size Inspector. Even if I programatically resize the cell using collectionViewLayout

Answer (score -1):

Adding to Βασίλης Δ's answer make sure to set the estimate size to none under your collection view size inspector. [image of Estimate Size in size inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFO97.png)

Comment: please try to provide detailed and precise answer

Comment: @Dr.Arslan If you let it estimate the cell size it will sometimes estimate the size of the cell which will show an undesired size for performance reason