# How to resize CollectionView cell height according to image in cell in swift?

Tags: ios

How to give the size to CollectionView cell according to image displaying in it?

Comment: collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath .Use this method, moreover follow this [resizing link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974973/how-to-resize-the-collection-view-cells-according-to-device-screen-size)

Comment: I've already used it but my control is not going to that method.....

Comment: Check whether you have set collectionView delegate or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to confirm protocol called `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
// EXTENSION FOR Controller class
extension Controller:UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{


    // NUMBER OF SECTION IN TABLE
    public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    // NUMBER OF ROWS IN PARENT SECTION
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return Array.count

    }
    // The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

        let Cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ControllerCell
        Cell.menuHeader.text = Array[indexPath.row]
        return parentCell
    }

    // SIZE FOR COLLECTION VIEW CELL
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 150)
         }
```

Comment: Yes, now its going to that method and changing the size of cell. thanks a lot.

Comment: @VivekTyagi no problem